# Disable all server routing except for api calls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, routes, angular2-routing

I have created a angular2 project using ASP.net with webapi. I have everything setup correctly and working but when I am routing in angular2 such as: "localhost:1234/login" the source of the page is displaying the error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

This is obviously because of server routing that cant find any path for this. My question is: Is there any way to disable all routing by the server except for if I'm doing a call like: "localhost:1234/api/login" because that would entail making a server request to a webapi controller which will return JSON. I want angular2 to handle all forms of routing. And the server just to handle data being pushed out.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If Angular is generating views by consuming APIs this should not be an issue. If the server is expected to serve up HTML for the routes Angular is calling then it needs equivalent routing configured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in your startup.cs class.

You need to configure the way your API calls are made in a way, and redirect to your index.html otherwise like so :

```
        app.UseMvc(r =>
        {   
            r.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{path?}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            r.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        });
```